# analizar xml con linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

necesito por favor, ver si alguien me puede alumbrar un poco, ya que tengo un xml con informacion acerca de alertas de un medicamento que se obtiene desde un servicio REST publicado en un server.
la respuesta viene en formato xml, y estoy tratando de leerla con linq

esta es la respuesta que debo analizar:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title>Prescription Analysis</title>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="/rest/api/alerts" />
  <id>/rest/api/alerts</id>
  <updated>2017-07-20T00:00:00Z</updated>
  <entry xmlns:vidal="http://api.vidal.net/-/spec/vidal-api/1.0/" vidal:categories="PRESCRIPTION_LINE">
    <title>piroxicam * 10 mg ; vía oral ; cápsula dura</title>
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="/rest/api/vmp/376" />
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://side_effect/376/14863" />
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://indicator/IS_NOT_COMMUNALLY_AGREED" />
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://warning/376/2373" />
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://side_effect/376/14873" />
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://side_effect/376/29493" />
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://side_effect/376/18634" />
    <category term="PRESCRIPTION_LINE" />
    <author>
      <name>VIDAL</name>
    </author>
    <id>vidal://vmp/376</id>
    <updated>2017-07-20T00:00:00Z</updated>
    <content />
    <vidal:safetyAlert>true</vidal:safetyAlert>
    <vidal:type>COMMON_NAME_GROUP</vidal:type>
    <vidal:code>376</vidal:code>
  </entry>
  <entry xmlns:vidal="http://api.vidal.net/-/spec/vidal-api/1.0/" vidal:categories="ALERT">
    <title>Contraindicación absoluta : PIROXICAM 10 mg cápsula dura</title>
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://vmp/376" />
    <category term="ALERT" />
    <author>
      <name>VIDAL</name>
    </author>
    <id>vidal://contraindication/376/9021/1</id>
    <updated>2017-07-20T00:00:00Z</updated>
    <content type="text/html">Contraindicaci&amp;oacute;n absoluta entre PIROXICAM 10 mg c&amp;aacute;psula dura y Ni&amp;ntilde;o menor de 15 a&amp;ntilde;os</content>
    <vidal:type>CONTRA_INDICATION</vidal:type>
    <vidal:alertType name="CONTRA_INDICATION">Contraindicación</vidal:alertType>
    <vidal:severity>LEVEL_4</vidal:severity>
    <vidal:subType name="ABSOLUTE">absoluta</vidal:subType>
    <vidal:detail type="text/html" />
    <vidal:triggeredBy type="AGE" />
  </entry>
  <entry xmlns:vidal="http://api.vidal.net/-/spec/vidal-api/1.0/" vidal:categories="ALERT">
    <title>Efectos adversos: PIROXICAM 10 mg cápsula dura</title>
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://vmp/376" />
    <category term="ALERT" />
    <author>
      <name>VIDAL</name>
    </author>
    <id>vidal://side_effect/376/39584</id>
    <updated>2017-07-20T00:00:00Z</updated>
    <content type="text/html">Insomnio</content>
    <vidal:type>SIDE_EFFECT</vidal:type>
    <vidal:alertType name="SIDE_EFFECT">Efecto adverso</vidal:alertType>
    <vidal:severity>INFO</vidal:severity>
    <vidal:detail type="text/html">Frecuencia</vidal:detail>
  </entry>
  <entry xmlns:vidal="http://api.vidal.net/-/spec/vidal-api/1.0/" vidal:categories="ALERT">
    <title>Efectos adversos: PIROXICAM 10 mg cápsula dura</title>
    <link rel="inline" href="vidal://vmp/376" />
    <category term="ALERT" />
    <author>
      <name>VIDAL</name>
    </author>
    <id>vidal://side_effect/376/14113</id>
    <updated>2017-07-20T00:00:00Z</updated>
    <content type="text/html">Edema de las extremidades inferiores</content>
    <vidal:type>SIDE_EFFECT</vidal:type>
    <vidal:alertType name="SIDE_EFFECT">Efecto adverso</vidal:alertType>
    <vidal:severity>INFO</vidal:severity>
    <vidal:detail type="text/html">Frecuencia</vidal:detail>
  </entry>
  <entry xmlns:vidal="http://api.vidal.net/-/spec/vidal-api/1.0/" vidal:categories="PATIENT">
    <title>Patient</title>
    <link rel="self" href="vidal://patient/1" title="Patient" />
    <category term="PATIENT" />
    <author>
      <name>VIDAL</name>
    </author>
    <id>vidal://patient/1</id>
    <updated>2017-09-05T16:21:09Z</updated>
    <content />
    <vidal:gender>MALE</vidal:gender>
    <vidal:height>180.0</vidal:height>
    <vidal:hepaticInsufficiency>SEVERE</vidal:hepaticInsufficiency>
    <vidal:dateOfBirth>Thu Nov 08 15:44:50 CET 2012</vidal:dateOfBirth>
    <vidal:creatin>120</vidal:creatin>
    <vidal:weight>80.0</vidal:weight>
    <vidal:breastFeeding>NONE</vidal:breastFeeding>
    <vidal:weeksOfAmenorrhea>5</vidal:weeksOfAmenorrhea>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

en esta respuesta, necesito obtener todos los nodos que contengan `<vidal:type>CONTRA_INDICATION</vidal:type>`, o bien  `<vidal:severity>LEVEL_4</vidal:severity>`.

estoy utilizando la siguiente consulta linq, para poder obtener la informacion:

```
 XElement xmldoc = XElement.Parse(responseFromServer);

            XElement query = (from item in xmldoc.XPathSelectElements("severity") select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

pero no se entregan resultados (la variable query = null).

Comment: solo como nota.. como existe la propiedad xmlns, me parece que antes de severity deberias apendarle la ruta del xml, probalo porque no estoy seguro que sea tu problema particular.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. el xml no me es posible modificarlo, ya que es una respuesta de un servicio que consulto en un server.

Comment: por eso... no digo que modifiques el xml.. pero al tener esa propiedad el xmldoc enbebe a todos los nodos con esa direccion.. o sea que puede ser que en realidad la ruta al nodo sea http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom/severity

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por la coolaboracion

Comment: Si te sirvio alguna de las respuestas, por favor aceptala, asi es como funciona el sitio, mas que con un comentario de gracias. las gracias quedan implicitas al aceptar respuestas y dar reputacion por ellas ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que debes usar es el método [`Descendants(XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx),y utilizar el namespace en la búsqueda. Algo así debe funcionarte:

```
XElement xmldoc = XElement.Parse(responseFromServer);
XNamespace ns = "http://api.vidal.net/-/spec/vidal-api/1.0/";
var xmlelement = xmldoc.Descendants(ns+ "type").Where(x=>x.Value== "CONTRA_INDICATION");
```

---

Tras releer la pregunta entiendo que quieres todo el nodo. Para eso,simplemente accede al `Parent` de los descendientes que cumplan el criterio:

```
var xmlelement = xmldoc.Descendants(ns+ "type").Where(x=>x.Value== "CONTRA_INDICATION").Select(y=>y.Parent);
```

Comment: Bueno, consideremos mi respuesta como una alternativa. Excelente. Desconocia  esa sobrecarga de `Descendants`

Comment: @Einer De hecho había enlazado a la documentación de la sobrecarga sin parámetros. Editado :)

Answer (score 1):

Con un foreach que busque cada elemento `entry` y por cada `entry`, los elementos `type` y `severity` para comprarlos si tienen los valores LEVEL_4 o CONTRA_INDICATION:

```
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load("ruta o stream del xml");
            XElement feedElement = document.FirstNode as XElement;

 List<XElement> elementosEncontrados = new List<XElement>();
            // buscamos todos los descendientes del elemento feed
            foreach (XElement elemento in feedElement.Descendants())
            {
                // verificamos si es entry
                if (elemento.Name.LocalName == "entry")
                {
                    // como es un entry, buscamos los elementos type y severity para comprarlos con los valores
                    foreach (XElement entryData in elemento.Descendants().Where(X => X.Name.LocalName == "type" || X.Name.LocalName == "severity"))
                    {
                        // si uno de los 2 valores dan true, entonces tenemos lo que buscamos
                        if (entryData.Value == "LEVEL_4" || entryData.Value == "CONTRA_INDICATION")
                        {
                            elementosEncontrados.Add(elemento);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

Console.WriteLine($"Cantidad elementos encontrados: " + elementosEncontrados.Count());

// aqui analizas los elementos que tienen los valores que filtraste.
```